# Sidebars not displaying in Wordpress theme Mantra and header cropping over advised size

Tags: wordpress, header, themes, sidebar

I have installed Mantra as my WP theme, can't find help to this two issues. 
1) Sidebars are not showing. I have a child theme with funtions.php and stylesheet.php folders. The theme comes with possibilities for 1-4 columns and sidebars left, right or both. I was explained can't have sidebars in the frontpage or as theme calls it, presentation page. If I could still add them, I would be extremely happy. However, my main issue is, I can't get sidebars to display in my post pages. I removed the view of pages and I'm using Categories instead since my page is news based. The main theme has sidebar php and action as been called into my child theme. Sidebars do exist since I can insert in the footer. It's just sidebars that are not working. I use for choosing where to display the Jetpack widget visibility. I need the sidebars so visitors can navigate my site between categories and want to display other content as well.
2) I have created an image, to the exact size theme advises and as per theme, it will be posted as is if the image has the exact measurements. However, no matter what I do, it does not displays as is and keeps cropping my image in half when I try to submit it.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you to solve sidebar & crop issue

> http://wordpress.org/support/theme/mantra